# Walk folder tree, bottom up

Tags: c#, .net, recursion, directory, binary-tree

I'm looking for ideas for fast and effective way to walk through folders **bottom-up** using C#/.NET 3.5

for example:

-0
--1
---12
--2
---21
---22
---23

first walk though: 12,21,22,23
then: 1,2

Thanks

Comment: You'll wind up at the root of the tree.  Do you just want to walk that specific branch?

Comment: walk all branches, order is not important as long as they are in the same "level"

Comment: Then I would suggest walking the tree in the usual way, from the root, and keeping only the nodes you want. If you only want nodes at a specific level, you can keep track of the level you're at with a counter, and toss out all of the nodes you don't need.

Comment: ok, but I need all of them, I don't want to make hundreds of temporary Lists<> to keep track, I wanted to do this within one function that would return me IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Walk the tree the usual way, and add an object containing each node and the level of the node to an `IEnumerable`.

```
public class DirectoryNode
{
    public DirectoryInfo Dir { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<DirectoryNode> myNodes;
```

Then, to get your list, just call your resulting `IEnumerable` with the `OrderByDescending` linq extension method, like this:

```
var result = myNodes.OrderByDescending(node => node.Level);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the depth of each node and you need to find the maximum depth of all nodes before starting to traverse the tree. So you need to traverse all nodes in a preorder, inorder, or postorder traversal, find their depths, and then traverse the whole tree again in reverse order of depth.